# Custom interceptor for adding headers not sending the message with updated headers

Tags: soap, http-headers, client, cxf, interceptor

I do something like this

```
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
            client.getInInterceptors().add(new HeaderHandler());

            try {
                port.[my method](inputs);
}
```

And my handler looks like

```
public class HeaderHandler extends LoggingInInterceptor {

    public HeaderHandler() {
        super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault {
        Map<String, List<String>> headers = CastUtils.cast((Map<String, List<String>>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS));
        List<String> clientid = new ArrayList<String>();
        clientid.add("");
        headers.put("clientid", clientid);

        List<String> authorization = new ArrayList<String>();
        authorization.add("Basic @#$%#$%^#$^");
        headers.put("Authorization", authorization);

        message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);
        System.out.println("called");
    }
}
```

The handle message method is always called and debugging through I can find the headers I created within the message saved before the method concludes but when the port method resolves I have just the default headers again sent in the soap request

```
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], cache-control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[494], content-type=[application/soap+xml; action="urn:[my method]"; charset=UTF-8], host=[localhost:8080], pragma=[no-cache], user-agent=[Apache-CXF/3.1.8]}
```

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check CXF FAQ: [How can I add soap headers to the request/response?](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIaddsoapheaderstotherequest/response?), I suggest to use the CXF way

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);

// Add HTTP headers to the web service request
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
headers.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList(authorization));
headers.put("clientid", Arrays.asList(clientid));
proxy.getRequestContext().put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);

// Add SOAP headers
List<Header> soapheaders = new ArrayList<Header>();
Header dummyHeader = new Header(new QName("uri:org.apache.cxf", "dummy"), "decapitated", new JAXBDataBinding(String.class));
soapheaders.add(dummyHeader);
client.getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, soapheaders);
```

Comment: P.S. apparently the only thing I was missing to get my solution to work was the HeaderHandler needed to be an outInterceptor instead of an inInterceptor. I have no idea why but your solution is much better!

Comment: Opps, I didn't see it. In the client side, an OUT interceptor is executed from `client --> server` and IN interceptor from `server --> client`, so you were modifying received headers!